# Python Beautifulsoup:how to get rid of '\n' in the texts of html tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've tried to write data to a csv file using python:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
ticketCount=soup.find_all('span',id='ticket_count')
records.append(ticketCount)
```

But what I got is:

```
<span id=""ticket_count"">15695.3\n                   \u4e07\n            </span>]
```

there are some annoying '\n' in the text, how can I get rid of them and make my output more elegant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_text(strip=True)`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
ticketCount = soup.find('span', id='ticket_count').get_text(strip=True)
print(ticketCount)
```